# Count Wordpress posts by year with SQL

Tags: sql, wordpress, web-applications

How can i count all Wordpress posts published  in a certain year(for eg. 2010) directly from the database using SQL?

PS: I managed to do it using the Wordpress Api [query_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) function, but i would also like the sql query for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are interested in the published posts:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM wp_posts
WHERE YEAR(post_date) = 2010
AND post_type = 'post'
AND post_status = 'publish'
```

where `wp_posts` is the default posts table name, adjust with whatever prefix you chose if you changed it.

Comment: This is sub-optimal since `YEAR(post_date)` cannot use an index. If there are not many posts in the table, it won't make much of a difference, though.

Comment: shows 50 less then what i got from wp query posts..any idea why?

Comment: Forget about that :) my eyes are to blame for this. The output is just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Along the lines of

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS PostCount 
FROM
  PostTable 
WHERE 
  PostDate BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2011-01-01'
```

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_posts WHERE post_date BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2011-01-01' AND post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'`